# Delete indeterminate and infinite expressions

Tags: list-manipulation

I am calculating a List on Mathematica and I get the results:

[image]

[image]

Is there any command that allows me to get rid of these results? This is because when I plot a Histogram the results mess up my distribution.

Thanks!

Comment: `DeleteCases[data, Infinity | Indeterminate | ComplexInfinity]`?

Comment: or `DeleteCases[data, _?(Not@*NumericQ)]`. The details depend on what the structure of your list is. Can you please give an example of a list, and what you would like the result to look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
DeleteCases[data, _DirectedInfinity | Indeterminate]
```

`Infinity` and `ComplexInfinity` are just different manifestations of [`DirectedInfinity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirectedInfinity.html).

There is another expression that can come up sometimes, [`Undefined`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Undefined.html). I do not think that this can arise from arithmetic though.

Finally, you can get rid of all non-numbers using

```
Select[data, NumericQ]
```

Here's a tricky thing about `NumericQ`:

```
expr = (E^(I Pi/5) - (-1)^(1/5))/(E^(I Pi/4) - (-1)^(1/4));
```

Now

```
NumericQ[expr]
(* True *)
```

but

```
N[expr]

During evaluation of Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/(0. +0. I) encountered.

During evaluation of Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/(0. +0. I)^1. encountered.

During evaluation of Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression (0. +0. I) ComplexInfinity encountered.

(* Indeterminate *)
```

So you may want to use `N[data]` immediately. If you do, you can also use [`NumericQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html) instead of [`NumericQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html).

Comment: `N[expr]` can lead to underflow and then to indeterminate or infinite expressions.  But even with `N[expr, prec]`  there are edge cases within the bounds of `$MinNumber` and `$MaxNumber`. (+1)