# Delete a whole nested list if one of the values in that list contains an "Indeterminate" value

Tags: list-manipulation

I'd like to delete a whole nested list if one of the values in that list contains an "Indeterminate" value.

The link below provides a solution to delete individual "Indeterminate" values:

[Delete indeterminate and infinite expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195177/delete-indeterminate-and-infinite-expressions)

However, is there a way to delete a whole nested list, if at least one value of that list is Indeterminate.

For example.

```
a = {{1,2,3},{4,5,Indeterminate},{7,8,9},{10,11,12}}
```

Becomes

```
a = {{1,2,3},{7,8,9},{10,11,12}}
```

Comment: Consider also positive filtering, e.g. `Cases[a, {__?NumericQ}]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, Indeterminate}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}} /. 
  {___, Indeterminate, ___} -> Nothing
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}} *)
```

One other consideration: we generally recommend that you avoid using capital letters to begin your symbols, to avoid colliding with built-in symbols.

Comment: Thank you. I've corrected the the text based on your comment

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Select`

```
A // Select[Not@MemberQ[#, Indeterminate] &]
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Some other options

```
Select[ContainsNone[{Indeterminate}]][a]
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}} *)

Pick[a, ContainsNone[{Indeterminate}] /@ a]
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,Indeterminate}, {7,8,9}, {10,11,12}, {Indeterminate, 0}}
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3) with `OrderlessPatternSequence`

```
Join @@ SequenceSplit[a, {{OrderlessPatternSequence[Indeterminate, __]}}]
```

{{1, 2, 3}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}

via `Position`

```
p = List /@ Position[a, Indeterminate][[All, 1]]
```

{{2}, {5}}

Using `Delete`

```
Delete[p] @ a
```

{{1, 2, 3}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[a, _ :> Nothing, p]
```

{{1, 2, 3}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}

Answer (score 1):

```
l = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, Indeterminate}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, {Indeterminate, 0}};
```

Grabbing the @eldo's list and using `SequenceCases`:

```
SequenceCases[l, {s : {__?RealValuedNumericQ}} :> s]

(*{{1, 2, 3}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using operator forms:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, Indeterminate}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}

DeleteCases[_?(ContainsAny[{Indeterminate}])][a]
DeleteCases[{___, Indeterminate, ___}][a]
Select[FreeQ[Indeterminate]][a]
Delete[Position[a, Indeterminate] // Map[First]][a]
Cases[{Except[_Complex, _?(NumericQ)] ..}][a]
```

---

*Result(s):*

> {{1, 2, 3}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}

Comment: +1, but `Cases[{__?NumericQ}][a]` would be simpler

Comment: I was answering multiple questions on the same notebook and the solutions got jumbled up. Thanks for catching this. @eldo